# Error playing video with vlcj

Tags: java, macos, media-player, vlcj

I'm developing a media player using vlcj 3.8 library, JDK 1.8 and Netbeans. When I follow these [instructions](http://capricasoftware.co.uk/#/projects/vlcj/tutorial/direct-rendering)  exactly the project gives me the following errors:

```
[00007ffc078e7b38] core vout display error: Failed to change zoom
[00007ffc078e7b38] core vout display error: Failed to set on top
[00007ffc078e7b38] core vout display error: Failed to change source AR.


Here is the complete log:

12 [main] INFO uk.co.caprica.vlcj.Info - vlcj: <version not available>
12 [main] INFO uk.co.caprica.vlcj.Info - java: 1.8.0_60 Oracle Corporation
12 [main] INFO uk.co.caprica.vlcj.Infenter code hereo - java home: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_60.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
13 [main] INFO uk.co.caprica.vlcj.Info - os: Mac OS X 10.11.1 x86_64
64 [main] INFO uk.co.caprica.vlcj.discovery.NativeDiscovery - Discovery found libvlc at '/Applications/VLC.app/Contents/MacOS/lib'
1669 [AWT-EventQueue-0] INFO uk.co.caprica.vlcj.binding.LibVlcFactory - vlc: 2.2.1 Terry Pratchett (Weatherwax), changeset 2.2.1-0-ga425c42
1669 [AWT-EventQueue-0] INFO uk.co.caprica.vlcj.binding.LibVlcFactory - libvlc: /Applications/VLC.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/libvlc.dylib
[00007ffc078e7b38] core vout display error: Failed to change zoom
[00007ffc078e7b38] core vout display error: Failed to set on top
[00007ffc078e7b38] core vout display error: Failed to change source AR
```

Comment: Does the video/media actually play or not? Those errors in my experience are redundant.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!!! You were right, those errors are redundant, I had another error with the layout and the videoPanel, when I fixed those errors everything worked. Thanks again.

Comment: What exactly was the error? And the fix? I also get these messages, and they are spamming stderr. Unacceptable in a production environment.

Comment: Yay, I found that these messages can be trapped using VLJj:s NativeLog. See e.g. https://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/14563188/ and of course http://caprica.github.io/vlcj/javadoc/3.8.0/index.html

Answer (score 1):

From [official site](http://capricasoftware.co.uk/#/projects/vlcj/tutorial/prerequisites)

> On OSX, there are potentially critical limitations if you use any version of Java after the 1.6 version. This is because in Java 1.7 on OSX there is no longer any "heavyweight" window toolkit, everything is lightweight. This is a problem because VLC requires the window handle of a heavyweight window so it can be told where to render the video into. What this means in practice is that the EmbeddedMediaPlayerComponent will not work on any Java version later than 1.6 on OSX. All is not lost, but life is harder for you as an application developer, since you will need to use a DirectMediaPlayerComponent instead.

We need to see you code, because we need to know wich component you use.

Comment: Mh.. you have used EmbeddedMediaPlayerComponent instead DirectMediaPlayerComponent ?